# How to make webpages with the same design

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

After many practice websites, I have finally made a website that is published. The problem is that if I need to change the design, i.e what is after and before (in coding) of the text that is going to be changed in every page, then I will have to change that in each of the files. Can anyone tell me about any way by which I can just change the code below and above the text. Any tag, code, software, etc that could help me, please.
Thank you

Comment: can you show some code and requirement with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid repeated html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177995/avoid-repeated-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP to include header and footer.

For example, you put all the header and the menu in "header.html" and all the footer, copyright, ... in "footer.html".

The, create a index.php. In this page, you may write like that :

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>
<p>body</p>
<?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
```

Comment: If I put the metas in the header file and then use the include command, then would my website be displayed in the search engines proporly.

Comment: Yes! without problems ! 90% of the internet works with that inclusions, don't worry ^^

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy; seperate your template files.

```
// header.php
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My beautiful website</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        ....
    </head>
    <body>
```

.

```
// footer.php
    </body>
</html>
```

.

```
// content.php
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<h1>Welcome on my website</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Now if you want to change something, change header.php and the changes will be visible on every content page.

Note; you can also turn things around (include 'content.php' from within a base template file)

Comment: This is by far the most comprehensive answer to the question. Thanks for the clarity and explanation.

Comment: If I put the metas in the header file and then use the include command, then would my website be displayed in the search engines proporly.

Comment: As you will see in the source code when viewing your site in the browser the meta tags will be shown on every page. So yes, search engines will read out the meta tag data (although meta tags aren't that important anymore nowadays). But I can imagine you want other tags on page x than on page y, so you just might want to separate those too, or fetch the tags from a database or something like that. When your site gets a bit bigger and more complicated, take a look at a framework, it'll make your life easier! (Checkout kohana or symphony for example)

Answer (score 1):

Divide your code into 3 `.php` files

1. `header.php`  - everything above your content
2. `content.php` - your content
3. `footer.php` - everything under your content

Then in your `index.php` file ( and all the others ) just include them, like:

```
<?php
$meta = 'This page meta info';

include('header.php');
include('content.php');
include('footer.php');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<html>
    <meta="<?php echo $meta; ?>" />
    ...
```

Comment: If I put the metas in the header file and then use the include command, then would my website be displayed in the search engines proporly.

Comment: you have to define your meta (and all the unique data per page) before the include and later just refer to those variables - see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use includes 
      `<?php include('templates/global_header.tpl') ?>`

to do this you need your main pages to have the extention .php instead of html.