# PHP Meta page description

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a different meta descriptions for each page. However I've tried multiple meta checkers and all of them are saying that no meta descriptions can be found?

In my headers.php file I use the following code:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pagedescription; ?>" />
```

Then on each page I would add this code:

```
<?php $pagedescription = 'example description here'; ?>
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you saying you end up with an empty placeholder or that you're getting an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing metas for each page in PHP Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063273/changing-metas-for-each-page-in-php-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely loading the headers.php file before the code setting the variable, ensure that $description = 'meta' is done before  echo $description.