# Creating several webpages sharing a navigational menu

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid repeated html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177995/avoid-repeated-html)

I'm planning to create a website with many webpages which are shared by a navigational menu.

For example: www.apple.com

Do I have to create separate html files with the same menu code or is there an easier way to accomplish the same task? (using javascript, php, etc)

(using Dreamweaver CS3)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with file includes or master pages in bundles programming languages.

Here is a website that goes into detail on includes in a variety of those different languages.

[Link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options. You could have a menu div to contain the menu. Then use a javascript resource to update it when the page loads.

Alternatively you could use a CMS like Joomla to define a template for your site and then create pages within that template. This would likely be your prefered route as it avoids the accessibilty issues of javascript and enable you to easily retheme your site if you wish (e.g. Halloween branding for a sale etc.)

Answer (score 0):

for php 
make a file with name nav.php 
add all code for navigation bar in it 
and after that include this file in all the other webpages with proper location
using following code

```
include "nav.php";
```

for example

```
<body>
<?php include "nav.php" ?>

<!--some other elements -->
</body>
```