# Store LINK elements and SCRIPT elements in a separate file

Tags: html

We may have to place lot of LINK elements and SCRIPT elements in the head elements of an HTML page. Also there can be a lot of pages with same above mentioned elements. Therefore can we put all the of them in a one file and place only that links containing file in HTML head element?

Eg: Something like,

```
<link href="links.something"> etc
```

instead of

```
<HEAD>

<link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/images.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>`

<HEAD>
```

Comment: You should minify and combine your CSS and JS files in a production site. That way, you only load one CSS and one JS file (maybe jQuery or some other libraries from a CDN).

Comment: Honestly, why does it matter? If you try to condense all you are doing is adding to the loading time.

Comment: @Blender: Is there a procedure or tools for this?

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka: Something like this should work: http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool

Comment: @bobthyasian: In my web site I have 100+ pages. Therefore when I add new or delete an elements I have to edit all the pages. For and example I am going to upgrade jquery 1.8... to 1.9... I have to edit all the pages. But if I had only one page with all elements in a separate page it is much easy. Something like keep PHP database connection in a separate file.

Comment: Thanks Blender, I will have a look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid repeated html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177995/avoid-repeated-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it would be best to do PHP `include`s 
 For example a page would be coded in parts: `header.php`, `footer.php`, and the main content would be loaded dynamically too.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php 
include('header.php'); //PHP file that holds all the links(not anchor links) and scripts
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include('body.php?page=whatever');
include('footer.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

By doing so, you'd only have to edit one file to make changes to many.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But is it a standard way? Because I have never seen a php part in a head element. But it did the trick.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about that. Only client-side scripting, such as javascript. It's actually how most CMSs (like WordPress) work.

Comment: I mean is it a standard/ good way to do it as a programmer? Since it has a standard way to place elements in html.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. So long as you keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate them dynamically from a server-side script (say, PHP), I've sen this done using the CodeIgniter MVC framework, though you could do it with straight PHP.

You could also use a templating engine (like Smarty) to do the same thing.

Straight php:

```
<head>
include('js_files.php');
</head>
```

CI MVC (in the controller), this is fairly involve & there are much better examples on the web:

```
$jsfiles = $this->load->model('head_files');
$head = $this->load->view('head', $jsfiles, false);
```

I'm not sure about Smarty as I'm only starting in it myself, this is the main reason I started with it, unfortunately I've lost the link to the tutorial I saw.

Comment: I am not familiar with php frameworks and templating engine. Any tutorials or examples please.