# Can I extend\include static html pages?

Tags: html, templates, inheritance, include, extend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid repeated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177995/avoid-repeated-html)

I have 2 static html pages:

- **main.html**
  This contains my html, head and body tags.
  In it I have also put in links to css stylesheets and javascript pages like jquery.
- **home.html**
  My home page which will welcome users.

I don't want to duplicate all the script references so I was hoping I could extend main.html into home.html.
I've not done this before with plain html pages so am not sure where to start.
I was also planning on putting in a header, footer and navigation bars into main.html and just want all my other pages to inherit it.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You got it right in the tags. Use some sort of HTML templating, either server-side or client-side, or a mix of both. Do you want to know how to do it? Then that's the question you should ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP and make a header.php footer.php etc

**home.html**

```
<?php include('file.php'); ?>
```

html normally