# creating universal navigation using ".innerHTML=("");

Tags: javascript, scripting, innerhtml

Im pretty new when it comes to js but what I Basically  wanted to do was create a universal navigation using the innerHTML method so i wouldnt have to replace whole html contents. I can just run the script on multiple pages and have all the links to my navigation change when editing the script. I made a minuture version of what I wanted to do using jsfiddle. My intention was to run the script from an external .js file, but for demonstration purposes i inserted the script directly in.

```
<script>document.getElementById("navigation").innerHTML=
              ("<a href="index.html"><li>home</li></a>
                <a href="portfolio.html"><li>portfolio</li></a>
                <a href="resources.html"><li>resources</li></a>
                <a href="projects.html"><li>projects</li></a>");
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/auk2/sR6aM/

Answer (score 1):

- You can't have literal line break inside a JavaScript string literal
- You can't have unescaped `"` characters in a string delimited by them
- `<li>` elements may not be child elements of `<a>` elements (the reverse isn't true)

I'd avoid client side includes in favour of [something more reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177995/avoid-repeated-html) for this anyway.